# How to create different file names for every new document in Photoshop?

Tags: filenames, photoshop

I have an A4 size document with 6 Photos, while I am trying to cut one photo from the original and create a new document the new file name is created as "Untitled-1".

Since I am using an Action to cut from original and paste it into the new document, every new file is opened with same name as "Untitled-1" and while saving it replaces the existing.

Is there any way to make every new document with sequence number or any different names for each file while create new document in Photoshop?

Or else please suggest if any script is available for the same.

Please find below screenshot for your clear understanding.

thanks in advance.

[Full page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOEVk.jpg)

[Every new document name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWaGZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with slices? It's beneath the crop tool - You can slice up your document the way you want it, then Export > Save for web, then each slice will save as an individual file.